# Illegal NSTableView data source in swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, nstableview

I can find no answers or solutions to a problem such as this for swift 4. I am writing for OSX and when I reload the data in my `tableView` with `tableView.reloadData()`, the terminal returns the error -

> Illegal NSTableView data source ().  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and
>   tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

To my knowledge I have implemented `numberOfRowsInTableView` and `tableView` in the extension.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
    import Cocoa

    class ViewController2: NSViewController {


    var data: [[String: String]]?

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        data = [
                [
                    "type" : "type1",
                    "details"  : "etc",
                    "cost" : "22"
                ],
                [
                    "type" : "type2",
                    "details"  : "etc",
                    "cost" : "33"
                ],
                [
                    "type" : "type3",
                    "details"  : "etc",
                    "cost" : "44"
            ]
        ]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}

extension ViewController2: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate{

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return (data?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let item = (data!)[row]
        let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn!.identifier), owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
        cell?.textField?.stringValue = item[(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]!
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reorganizing your code so that your tableview methods are inside your class instead of the extension?

Comment: You must implement this method "tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the Swift 4 API for the `NSTableViewDataSource` method. Instead of

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {}
```

Use these correct APIs:

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
```

See the official documentation for the data source API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdatasource

Comment: `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` of `NSTableViewDataSource` is not the Swift 4 version of `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` of `NSTableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Yes indeed I read it too fast, there is only the `numberOfRowsInTableView` method which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

My only solution was to restart Xcode and Mac. There was nothing wrong with code. Someone might have same issue as I did.